# RecyclerView onCreateViewHolder does not run

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have search for hours and i'm sure its something simple but i can't find the answer. `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` does not run. can someone help me out. thanks

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mBlogList;

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog").limitToLast(50);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
  //  query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog").limitToLast(50);

    mBlogList = findViewById(R.id.blog_list);
    mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mBlogList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this)); //sets the orientation to vertical

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Toast.makeText(this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Blog> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Blog>()
            .setQuery(query, Blog.class)
            .build();
    Toast.makeText(this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.blog_row, parent, false);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "oh oh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return new BlogViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(BlogViewHolder holder, int position, Blog model) {

            holder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            holder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "oh si", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    };

    mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}


    public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

       View mView;

        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {

            TextView post_title = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
           post_title.setText(title);
        }

        public void setDesc(String desc) {

            TextView post_desc = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
           post_desc.setText(desc);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_add) {

            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Postctivity.class));

        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Blog.class**

```
public class Blog {

private String title;
private String desc;
private String image;

public Blog(){

}

public Blog(String title, String desc, String image) {
    this.title = title;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.image = image;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
}
```

**blog_row.xml**

```
public class Blog {
private String title;
private String desc;
private String image;

public Blog(){

}

public Blog(String title, String desc, String image) {
    this.title = title;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.image = image;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
}
```

Comment: What errors is it showing?Can you please attach the logcat or if explain in brief about the error that it throws?

Comment: I agree with @Mandy8055. You need to provide more information than "It doens't work."  What exactly happens?

Comment: The logcat doesn't throw any errors. The app doesn't crash either. it just doesn't display the contents of my firebase child using the row_layout. I try debugging it and the onCreateViewHolder never gets called. Sorry I'm a noob trying to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noob trying to learn here. The recyclerView was not downloading the content from the firebase database. What I did to fix it was changing the from `setHasFixedSize(true)` to `setHasFixedSize(false)` Im not sure why it fixed it but it did. I know my question is confusing my english is not very good. I hope this help.

Comment: Is your `RecyclerView` tag in the XML set to a fixed size? (e.g. 200dp tall, or `match_parent`) Or is it set to `wrap_content`?

Comment: I have it set to `wrap_content`

Comment: If you're using `wrap_content` in combination with `setHasFixedSize(true)` you have to be 100% sure that the first time the recycler view is laid out, it will have all of its children available and they will never change. Since your RV is hooked up to a firebase query, it will start with 0 children, and with a fixed size that means that even when the query returns info to display, the RV is locked to 0 size.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation for the library you're using](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#startstop-listening), you have to call `adapter.startListening()` to actually read information from your database.

> The `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` uses an event listener to monitor changes to the Firebase query. To begin listening for data, call the `startListening()` method. You may want to call this in your `onStart()` method. Make sure you have finished any authentication necessary to read the data before calling `startListening()` or your query will fail.
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onStart() {
>     super.onStart();
>     adapter.startListening();
> }
> ```

It looks like you're doing all the setup of your adapter in `onStart()` already, so I think you can just add one line at the end:

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
```